# AndroidDriver constructor rises NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, android, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, appium

I use Appium server running on Mac machine and AppiumDriver with c# bindings to execute tests from Windows machine. The issue is that when I create an instance of AndroidDriver its ctor rises a NullReferenceException. When I create an instance of RemoteWebDriver, it works smoothly. This is my code:

```
var caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
caps.SetCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DeviceName, "Nexus_4");
caps.SetCapability("udid", "<valid-device-id>");
caps.SetCapability(MobileCapabilityType.App, "https://valid/path/to/my.apk");
caps.SetCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PlatformName, MobilePlatform.Android);

using (var drv = new AndroidDriver(ServerUri, caps)) // rises exception
//using (var drv = new RemoteWebDriver(ServerUri, caps)) // works smoothly
{
    drv.GetScreenshot().SaveAsFile("Android.png", ImageFormat.Png);
}
```

Exception:

```
System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Result StackTrace:  
at OpenQA.Selenium.Appium.AppiumDriver._AddAppiumCommands()
at OpenQA.Selenium.Appium.AppiumDriver..ctor(Uri remoteAddress, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Appium.Android.AndroidDriver..ctor(Uri remoteAddress, DesiredCapabilities desiredCapabilities)
```

Where am I wrong? Why the constructor of AndroidDriver rises this execption and doesn't specify the reason?

Comment: [What is a `NullReferenceException` and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @SonerGönül, AndroidDriver has two parameters, and both of them are not null. Furthermore, RemoteWebDriver accepts the same params and works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bug resolved in most recent [Appium.Webdriver](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Appium.WebDriver/) version.

Comment: Hi, currently I am going through same issue and I found this post.
I am working on Appium Desktop version and struggling with AppiumDriver.
Let me know if it can be resolved